# Angular 1.5+ component optional one-way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-components

Taken from the AngularJS 1 [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile):

> You can also make the binding optional by adding `?` : `<?` or `<?attr`.

How does the optional one differ from the non-optional one for the one-way binding?

I can seem to figure out the differences for the optional version of two-way (`=`) and delegate (`&`) bindings here on my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/glenn/ze2wo0s1/, but not for the one-way one.

By the way, a very Merry Christmas! ❤️

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can see the how it's handled in the source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/compile.js#L3523.

To me, it looks like if you use `<?` and make the binding optional, it breaks early without setting up a watch. If use use `<` and make it required, it sets the binding to `undefined` and sets up a watch. However, it appears to be just watching `undefined`, so in practice, there's no difference at all except for that one call to `recordChanges`. In the case that you omit a required binding, the binding that's required will be a key in the `changes` object that is passed to `$onChanges` hook  on the first call. However, when you omit an optional binding, it will not be a key in the `changes` object.

For an example see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ze2wo0s1/5/). `requiredBinding` and `optionalBinding` are both omitted, and thus, initialized to `undefined`, but `requiredBinding` is a key on the `change` object, whereas `optionalBinding` is not.

Comment: Whoa, such a small detail. Thanks for this! :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `<?` makes it possible for the controller to change the value of the variable that was supposed to be bound, only if that variable is not present.

The optional bindings can be modified in the controller when they are NOT present. If the value is passed to the component, then there's no way of changing it.

The non-optional bindings can not be modified whatsoever. If they are not present, they are `undefined` and they can not be modified at all.

for example, assume you have this:

```
bindings: {
  nameOptional: '<?',
  nameRequired: '<'
}
```

In the controller, you **can not** simply do `$ctrl.nameRequired = 'something else'` and expect the view to get updated. However, you **can** do the same with `nameOptional` with one condition: only if `name-optional` is not passed to the component. Only then the variable is the controller's to change.

For better understanding you can refer [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a1t7r65a/).

Note that to simplify the thing, we're using a string which is passed by value. If you are passing objects, the object's properties can always get modified in normal conditions.